# how to pass an element from mounted to HTML template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I get some data from api in mounted. I'd like to pass them to html template by the loop, but it is still doesn't work.

HTML

```
  .date
                .values(v-for="el in document")
                    span {{el.created}}
                    span {{el.document_title}}
                .actions_value
                    .pic
                      i.fas.fa-download
                    span download
```

VUE.JS

```
     export default {
      data() {
       return {
         document: {}
        };
     },
     mounted() {
       co.getDocuments(
         this.$store.getters.customer_id,
         this.$store.getters.token
       ).then(data => {
         let dataDoc = data.data;
         console.log(dataDoc);

         Object.values(dataDoc).map(document => {
           return (this.document = document);
        });
       });
      }
    };
```

My el in the loop doesn't exist.I tried to assign a document to this.document. But still somenthig is wrong.

Comment: Can you after `Object.values` do `console.log(this.document);` and print result here. I think your document isn't array...

Comment: You have right. I have checked and it is not. It is a Object. This is mean I can't do a "map"?

Comment: Try to change in data `document: []`.

Comment: I changed. Now this.document is an array. But it still nothing want to pass to html. I dont have any errors in console.

Comment: Print here your console log

Comment: [__ob__: Observer]
length: 0
__ob__: Observer
dep: Dep {id: 123, subs: Array(1)}
value: Array(0)
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
vmCount: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Array

Comment: I found that my array is empty. So the data from dataDoc didnt pass. I mean my this.document is empty. But when I do this.document = document, and console.log this, I have some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the Vue component reference within the map function by using **this** keyword. So, I suggest you to bind the Vue component reference instead of the default this operator.

```
 Object.values(dataDoc).map(
  function(document) {
    this.document = document;
  }.bind(this) **// like this**
);
```

sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-3hmom